# Elsa workflow versioning

Tags: elsa-workflows

I have created a simple workflow, first time publish it is working fine when I change something and publish then it is throwing an exception: "The call is ambiguous and matches multiple workflows". How to handle this?

[image]

Comment: Looks like this bug still exists if you are using the latest (v2.2) packages. What persistence provider do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue. There appears to be an issue in Elsa where the "IsLatest" flag on the WorkflowDefinition table doesn't get turned off for the prior version of that workflow. There is some documentation around the issue here:

https://gitmemory.com/issue/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/1293/886656398

In my case, I fixed this by manually setting the prior version's IsLatest to 0 and restarting Elsa. The restart was important, as there appears to be some caching related to the workflow newness.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR : there are multiple workflows with the same path

Check if you are building a workflow through ELSA DESIGNER and at the same time there is a workflow that is triggered when HTTP requests are made to the **same URL**

```
public class HelloWorld : IWorkflow
{
    public void Build(IWorkflowBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .HttpEndpoint("/hello") // this is the endpoint that is causing conflict
            .When(OutcomeNames.Done)
            .WriteHttpResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "<h1>Hello World!</h1>", "text/html");
    }
}
```